# Nautilus looks bad in 16.04

Tags: nautilus, 16.04

Yesterday I upgraded my system from 15.10 to 16.04. Knowing that the nautilus file browser will looks slightly different, I took screenshots before and after the upgrade. I did not think it would look this bad.

Old:

[image: Old]

New:

[image: New]

Is this a bug? More importantly, can I do anything on my part to make it look better?

Comment: Well there's definitely something weird with the borders. You could see what reinstalling Nautilus does: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus && sudo dpkg-reconfigure nautilus`.

Comment: This didn't make a difference, unfortunately. I have noticed that if I use the default Ubuntu theme, the icons and text will be separated more (horizontally), but I still prefer the old look.

Comment: If you aren't using a default theme,  I'd expect problems. It's probably not updated to work with 16.04

Comment: just to know to myself, which theme are you using?

Comment: I use a theme I found on [NoobsLab.com](http://www.noobslab.com/p/themes-icons.html) (however I cannot currently find it), which I've modified to match the Ubuntu's default brown/dark grey color. I also took some icons from the [Yoseambiance](http://www.noobslab.com/2016/01/yosembiance-smooth-and-sleek-theme.html) theme.

I put the themes in my Dropbox folder for you:
[Ambiance Dark](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/164850521/Ambiance%20Dark.tar.gz), 
[Yoseambiance Dark](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/164850521/Yoseambiance%20Dark.tar.gz)

Comment: Let's have documentation everywhere: Note that **Nautilus** [is now **GNOME Files**](https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.6/users-files.html.en). For many users upgrading from 14.04 LTS 16.04 that might be confusing.

Comment: The actual package is still called `nautilus`, which is why I referred to it as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue with the theme I am using, however I was able to fix it by copying these lines (line 1340 to 1373) (the part under the "sidebar" comment) from the `gtk-widgets.css` file (`/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/`)...:

```
/***********
 * sidebar *
 ***********/
GtkPlacesSidebar.sidebar .view {
    background-color: shade (@bg_color, 0.95);

    color: @fg_color;
    text-shadow: 0 1px shade (shade (@bg_color, 0.95), 1.04);
}

GtkPlacesSidebar.sidebar:backdrop {
    color: mix (@fg_color, shade (@bg_color, 0.95), 0.2);
    text-shadow: 0 1px shade (shade (@bg_color, 0.95), 1.02);
}

GtkPlacesSidebar.sidebar row:selected {
    color: @selected_fg_color;
    text-shadow: 0 1px shade (@selected_bg_color, 0.7);
}

GtkPlacesSidebar.sidebar row:selected:backdrop {
    background-image: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, left bottom,
                                     from (shade (shade (@bg_color, 0.95), 0.94)),
                                     to (shade (shade (@bg_color, 0.95), 0.86)));
    border-top-color: shade (shade (@bg_color, 0.95), 0.88);

    color: @fg_color;
    text-shadow: 0 1px shade (shade (@bg_color, 0.95), 0.96);
}

GtkPlacesSidebar.sidebar .sidebar-icon {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

... over the "sidebar" part in the `gtk-widgets.css` file of the theme I use:

```
/***********
 * sidebar *
 ***********/
...
```

This is how Nautilus looks now:

[image: a busy cat]